# Convexity of a function defined by infimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $V$ be a real vector space, $C\subseteq V$ be a non-empty convex set, and $f:C\to \mathbb R$ be a function. Define $g:C\to \mathbb R$ by \begin{align} g(x) = \inf\left\lbrace \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k f(x_k) : x = \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_kx_k,\; \lambda_k>0,\; x_k\in C,\; \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k = 1,\;K\in \mathbb Z^+ \right\rbrace. \end{align}

I want to show that $g$ is a convex function. I thought I would require that $f$ should be convex, but in my proof I don't seem to need it. Am I missing something? Here is my proof.

We want to show that for every $x,y\in C$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$, \begin{align} g(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tg(x) + (1-t) g(y). \end{align}

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By definition of infimum, there exist convex combinations yielding $x$ and $y$: \begin{align} x = \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k x_k, \qquad y = \sum_{l=1}^L \mu_l y_k, \end{align} such that \begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k f(x_k) \leq g(x) + \epsilon, \qquad \sum_{l=1}^L\mu_l f(y_l) \leq g(y) + \epsilon. \end{align} Then, \begin{align} t \left(\sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k f(x_k)\right) + (1-t)\left(\sum_{l=1}^L\mu_l f(y_l)\right) \leq t g(x) + (1-t) g(y) + \epsilon,\end{align} from which we get $g(tx+(1-t)y) \leq t g(x) + (1-t) g(y) + \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we are done.

Comment: If $f$ is not convex, then there is no guarantee that the infimum in the definition of $g$ is a real number. On the other hand, if $f$ is convex, then by definition $g=f$.

Comment: @QiyuWen I see. Thanks for your comment. As I understand, if $f$ is not convex, we may have $g(x)\in [-\infty,\infty)$. After posting the question, I came across the notion of convex hull of a function: so in this case $g$ is the convex hull of $f$.